# Java Method that checks to see if an array is a Latin Square

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating a program with a method whose input is an 2D array of int, that checks to see if arrays are [Latin Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square).

For example a Latin Square would look like this:

```
1 2 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
```

This is my code so far:

```
public class LatinSquare {

  public boolean isLatinSquare(int[][] a){

    int[] row= new  int[a.length];
    int[] column = new int[a[0].length];

    for (int j = 0; j<column.length; j++){
      for (int i = 0; i<row.length;i++){
        row[i] = a[i][j];
      }

      for (int i = 0; i<row.length -1; i++){
        for (int x= i+1; x<=row.length;x++){
          if (row[i]==row[x]) 
            return false;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

The code is not fully complete but I just wanted to know if someone could answer some questions before I head in the wrong direction if I am doing something wrong.
My Question: Is this the best approach for checking arrays to see if they would fulfill a Latin Square? My thought process is that I start at column '0' and then go through the row comparing each number to each other making sure they are not equal, and move through each column this way. Is this the wrong way to be approaching this?

Comment: You need to do it in **tdd** way, write simple test for smallest permitted square.

Comment: I understand that, I am trying to create code so it returns false, returns false, then returns true if all the parameters are met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of nested loops will degrade performance. Here is a faster version, but it uses a bit more memory.

It relies on the values of the square being in the range `1` to `N`, where `N` is the square size.

```
private static boolean isLatinSquare(int[][] square) {
    boolean[][] foundInRow = new boolean[square.length][square.length];
    boolean[][] foundInCol = new boolean[square.length][square.length];
    for (int row = 0; row < square.length; row++) {
        if (square[row].length != square.length)
            return false; // Not a square
        for (int col = 0; col < square.length; col++) {
            int idx = square[row][col] - 1;
            if (foundInRow[row][idx] || foundInCol[col][idx])
                return false;
            foundInRow[row][idx] = foundInCol[col][idx] = true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(isLatinSquare(new int[][] { {1, 2, 3},
                                               {2, 3, 1},
                                               {3, 1, 2} }));
System.out.println(isLatinSquare(new int[][] { {1, 2, 3},
                                               {3, 1, 2},
                                               {2, 3, 1} }));
System.out.println(isLatinSquare(new int[][] { {1, 3, 2},
                                               {2, 1, 3},
                                               {3, 2, 1} }));
System.out.println(isLatinSquare(new int[][] { {1, 3, 2},
                                               {3, 2, 1},
                                               {2, 1, 3} }));
System.out.println(isLatinSquare(new int[][] { {1, 3, 2},
                                               {3, 2, 1},
                                               {1, 3, 2} }));
System.out.println(isLatinSquare(new int[][] { {1, 3, 1},
                                               {3, 2, 3},
                                               {2, 1, 2} }));
System.out.println(isLatinSquare(new int[][] { {1, 2, 3},
                                               {2, 3},
                                               {3, 1, 2} }));
```

*Output*

```
true
true
true
true
false
false
false
```

Comment: Thank you this will definitely help!

Comment: I am getting error codes on the "System.out.println(isLatinSquare(newint[][]...." code. It is asking me to rename the method, and there are errors on the brackets and parenthesis after each LatinSquare example i.e. "}))." Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @Luke Maybe the missing space between `new` and `int`? It's `new int[][]`, not `newint[][]`. Also, make sure to put the test code inside a method, e.g. the `main()` method.